# Aborting a request in vertx

Tags: vert.x

I have a create handler, which contains a validation method like this:

```
void create(){
    validate();
    .
    .
    .
    insertInDb();
    routingContext.response().setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.CREATED.code()).end(...));
    }
```

In validate method I checked inputs and if they are not valid, I write it in response:

```
void validate(){
if(input not valid){
   routingContext.response().setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE.code()).end();
}
}
```

the problem is that if inputs are not valid I want the handler to end. but what happens is that if inputs are not valid, it sets statusCode and writes in response, then it continues the flow in create method and when it runs the last line, it wants to write in response again and throws an exception. I want to end or abort the request when input is not valid. how can I do this?

}

Answer (score 1):

In Vert.x you can use multiple handlers for a route. If you have a route like `POST /users/login`, then you can have one handler that validates the request and calls the next handler only if it was valid. Now the second handler won't get called and you don't have the problem with sending the response again.

You can do it like this for example:

```java
...
router.post("/users/login")
  // first, the validation handler
  .handler((routingContext) -> {
    if(input not valid) {
      routingContext.response()
        .setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE.code())
        .end();
    } else {
      routingContext.next();
    }
  })
  // this handler will only be called if the input was valid!
  .handler((routingContext) -> {
    insertInDb();
    routingContext.response()
      .setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.CREATED.code())
      .end(...));
  });
...
```

You can find an example in the documentation [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_handling_requests_and_calling_the_next_handler).